# Obtaining maps of rings in gap

Tags: gap

Given a finite ring $A$ (a finite group would be enough actually as we do not use multiplication of the ring). Is it possible to obtain the ring $R$ (with usual addition and multiplication being given by composition) of all maps (not structure presserving) $A \rightarrow A$ as a ring in GAP? Is it possible to get $R$ as an $K$-algebra in case $A$ is an $K$-algebra?

For example can do this in the special case of $A= Z_n$ the ring of all integers mod $n$.

Comment: You might want to look at the SONATA package -- they have methods for constructing endomorphism rings.

Comment: @ahulpke Thanks. They have such a function for nearrings. Is there any way in GAP, using this package, to view a ring as a nearring (such as $Z_n$)?

Comment: You would have to look at the manual or contact the package authors.